# Requirement for transit visa Azerbaijan

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, transit-visas, azerbaijan

Iam an Indian citizen and studying in Ukraine. I want to go back India so I am planning to fly Azerbaijan airlines through BAKU. Do I need a transit Visa for the connecting flights?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a visa to connect through Azerbaijan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118353/do-i-need-a-visa-to-connect-through-azerbaijan)

Comment: @MichaelHampton: That answer is specific for US citizens.

Comment: @NateEldredge There's nothing specific to US citizens in the transit rules for Azerbaijan.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The linked answer doesn't state that it's not US specific.  Thus it's not a duplicate!

Comment: @Doc So what's the best way to fix that, without ending up with 200 questions each differing only by country of citizenship?

Answer (score 1):

[Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=IN&DV=India&TC=AZ&TV=Azerbaijan&h=3638e5987421cf6a872cb8c767d77fca5527bea) is the best source for such queries, which says that you don't need a visa.

It is also confirmed in the [FAQ](https://evisa.gov.az/en/apply-faq) of Official Electronic Visa Portal of Azerbaijan:

> Do I have to obtain a visa if I do not leave the international transit
>   area?
>
> **No. You do not have to get a visa if you are not going to leave the
>   international transit area.**